# Can I charge my MSI laptop with other brand charger?

Tags: laptop, charger

My MSI laptop charger is not working. So I thought to buy another one. But I couldn't find it in the market. My laptop input voltage is 20V-3.25A. Can I use the other brand charger with the same output voltage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop power adapter output compatibility](https://superuser.com/questions/1380439/laptop-power-adapter-output-compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

The voltage of the new charger should be identical (in practice up to 5% difference should be OK).   The current needs to be **NO LESS** then the stated 3.25 amp current - however a higher current is acceptable as a device will only draw the amount of power it needs.

You will also want to double check that ground and voltage are not reversed.  It is unlikely to be an issue, but getting this wrong could kill your laptop.  (Generally the inside is V+ and the outside is ground)

Be aware that many laptops communicate with the power supply - it is possible that a power supply which does not have additional logic to support the laptop may not charge at all, or may charge more slowly and/or pop up a warning message.

If you have a USB-C charger,  it should work fine as this is standardised protocol which will negotiate the appropriate connection - but try make sure it has a rating of at least 65 watts.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do when considering using a charger from another laptop is to check the connector. Many brands have similar connectors for their devices, however some laptop brands (such as Apple), have proprietary connectors that make it impossible to use other chargers.

You need to be careful when using other adapters because they will need to output the exact same DC voltage and the exact same or higher DC current (amps).

Be aware though, that jf the output voltage is different (higher or lower), if the output current is less (lower), or if the DC output connector doesn't match the style and wiring of your notebook, then you can damage your notebook or the AC/DC adapter can overheat and cause a fire if it is used.

Also be aware that it is possible that even if it's the correct amps and the connector is the same, it would still not charge the laptop. Often manufacturers place chips inside the adaptors which prevent them from being used with other laptops than intended.

[Source](https://ventiontech.com/blogs/technology-overview/can-you-use-any-laptop-charger-for-your-laptop)
[Source2](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/msi-notebook-with-other-ac-adapter.311033/)